# jQuery Mobile Tapping event highlight

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile page with jquery mobile and HTML5.

I want to change the div color(initially color is in black), when i am pressing(tapping or clicking) that div, i want to change that div's color to white from black  and after i removed my tapping i.e. after i took out my finger from that div i want to restore to black as before.

Is any event there for this kind?.Please help me in this.Thanks in advance.

```
<!--START:Initial state of  Div Where i want to change color to white when i press that div and change back to normal after i remove my finger-->
<div class="colorBlack inactive"><div>
<!--END:Initial state of Div Where i want to change color to white when i press that div and change back to normal after i remove my hand-->

<!--START: Div class is changed to colorWhite,when i am tapping that div or i am holding that div with my finger-->
<div class="colorWhite active"><div>
<!--END: Div class is changed to colorWhite,when i am tapping that div or i am holding that div with my finger-->


<!--START: Div class is changed back to colorBlack,when i remove my finger -->
<div class="colorBlack active"><div>
<!--START: Div class is changed back to colorBlack,when i remove my finger -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use touch start and touch end events for this.

```
$('#test').bind('touchstart', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
});

$('#test').bind('touchend', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
});​
```

Here is working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FaJt4/1/)

You can find more information about native DOM events on [MDN webstite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/TouchEvent).

Comment: Thanks For Ur Help.But the touchend event is not working for me.touchstart is working for me.

Comment: Working fine for me on demo page using ipad. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: it is working , if write after removing the bind from your code and replacing with the code jQuery(".mytap").touchstart(function(){
   jQuery(this).find("p").html('<span style="color:#F00;">Mouse up.</span>');
  }).touchend(function(){
    jQuery(this).find("p").html('<span style="color:#00F;">Mouse down.</span>');
  });

Comment: html is <div class="mytap"><p style="padding:30px;">tap test</p></div>

Comment: I guess you don't have any issues with this, it serves the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default touchbtn">Test</button>

$('.touchbtn').bind('touchstart', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
});

$('.touchbtn').bind('touchend', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
});
```